# Wait for finish the application version creation in AWS Boto3 for Elasticbeanstalk before environment creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I am creating a script to fast and automatically makes some basic management in AWS Elasticbeanstalk applications. You can check at https://github.com/danilocgsilva/smarteb, with the tag 1.0.2-dev2, which is the version of when I was writting this post.

To deploy a brand new environment, it is needed first to create an application version and after then creates the environment.

The part of script to do this is:

```
boto3client = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')

boto3client.create_application_version(
    ApplicationName=name,
    VersionLabel=versionAppName,
    SourceBundle={
        'S3Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-' + userId,
        'S3Key': name + '/' + versionAppName + '.zip'
    },
    Process=True,
)

boto3client.create_environment(
    ApplicationName=name,
    EnvironmentName=ebLocalConfigurator.getEnvironment(),
    SolutionStackName="64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.1 running PHP 7.4",
    OptionSettings=[
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
            'OptionName': 'IamInstanceProfile',
            'Value': 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role'
        },
    ],
    VersionLabel=versionAppName
)
```

If I put a command right after another, I receive an exception message:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: The application version version1 is processing. When the processing is complete, try launching the environment again.
```

Then I wondered if time is everything needed to wait the end of processing. So I put an wait of 5 seconds between two commands. And the things worked perfectly!

But it is not a good solution at my point of view. May 5 seconds is much more time needed to get things ready. Or worse, may some AWS internal process fluctuates and sometimes the application version creation may takes more than 5 seconds, breaking the script with an exception.

The ideal solution would be if boto3 offered some way to await until the application version creation finishes and then triggers the environment creation. Then the user will wait in the optimal time: things are triggered as soon as previous and dependent process finishes and also protects the application against time fluctuations.

Is there a way to trigger a command in boto3 and then await until it ends before triggering the next one?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, boto3 does not provide [waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#waiters) for this particular API call. The only **available waiters** are:

- ElasticBeanstalk.Waiter.EnvironmentExists
- ElasticBeanstalk.Waiter.EnvironmentTerminated
- ElasticBeanstalk.Waiter.EnvironmentUpdated

Therefore, you would have to **design your own waiter** for that. It could be in the form of basic `while` loop in python which checks the status of your application version every 5 seconds, until its ready.